# Difference of Community Wiki Edit and Normal Edit

Tags: discussion

Is there any difference between community wiki editing and normal answer editing. I can edit any question with just having 31 reputations so what does community wiki do except making restrictions for being edited by people under 100 reputations?

Comment: With 31 rep, you can _suggest_ edits to any post. Your suggestions need to be reviewed by at least three higher rep users. You'll be able to actually edit any post on your own only after you earn 2000 rep.

Comment: So can I edit a community wiki with my 31 reputations? @Yannis

Comment: @NavidRashidian: No, you'd be making suggested edits for CW posts as well, until you read 100 rep. CW posts also don't gain reputation or tag badges for the original author of the post.

Comment: By the way, in case you didn't notice, your suggested edit [was rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4100525).